# Keep text exactly N-lines long in JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to figure out how to calculate and set a width of a container div so that the text inside is exactly <=2 lines long. The problem is as follows: I am given a text, it's font properties and a "suggested" width 'X'px. I have to put the text into a div with width as close to the given 'X'px but ensure the text is wrapped into at most 2 lines.

Example:

```
text: 'total after-cashback revenue from rewarded users'
font: font-family: 'Roboto-Regular';font-size: 14px;line-height: 19px;
X: 130px

solution: 180px
because: 
    total after-cashback revenue // this is 180px
    from rewarded users
NOTE: if I put the text into 1 line and divide the width into 2 I get width 154px which results into:
    total after-cashback
    revenue from rewarded
    users
```

Example2:

```
text: 'total shit'
font: font-family: 'Roboto-Regular';font-size: 14px;line-height: 19px;
X: 130px

solution: 130px
because:
    total shit // ~60px < 130px soo 130px will be enough and it is 1 line
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Well I will go with this approach:

- Take the default space of px that creates the object with the limit size as base.
- Then take the value of two line-heights as max and evaluate if the actual height is greater than that.
- If it's more then reduce it to the max-height and do a Calc to ensure the same area of the base container complemented by the proportional increase on width.

Check this snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').each(function(){
    var $el   = $(this),
        maxH  = parseInt($el.css('line-height'))*2,
        actH  = $el.height(),
        actW  = $el.width();

    if(actH > maxH) {
      $el.height(maxH);
      var diff = actH/maxH;
      var newW = actW*diff
      $el.width(newW)
    }
  })
})
```

```css
div {
  margin:10px;
  line-height:20px;
  width:300px;  
  color:#e1e1e1; 
  background:tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae repellat nihil laudantium ipsa error, impedit quos consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae repellat nihil laudantium ipsa error, impedit quos , impedit quos consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae repellat nihil laudantium ipsa error, impedit quos</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae repellat nihil laudantium</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum</div>
```

---

#### Example with different font-sizes // line-heights:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').each(function() {
    var $el = $(this),
      maxH = parseInt($el.css('line-height')) * 2,
      actH = $el.height(),
      actW = $el.width();

    if (actH > maxH) {
      $el.height(maxH);
      var diff = actH / maxH;
      var newW = actW * diff
      $el.width(newW)
    }
  })
})
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  color: #e1e1e1;
  background: tomato;
}

div.two {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

div.third {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>total after-cashback revenue from rewarded users</div>
<div class="two">total after-cashback revenue from rewarded users</div>
<div class="third">total after-cashback revenue from rewarded users</div>
```

Comment: Hey, good approach but this does not take into consideration the font properties. Which can change everything

Comment: @mp3por how this doesn't take in care that ? It takes the important value that is line-height you can test it with your text example and multiple font-sizes/line-heights https://jsfiddle.net/kmuq4g0w/

Comment: @mp3por can you show an example when this script fails ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kmuq4g0w/2/ -> It will double-line the text even if it don't need to be.

Comment: @mp3por is the X value you define at the first must be at least to keep the words inside the area https://jsfiddle.net/kmuq4g0w/4/ ... if the words overflow the first container then the calc can't now which area proportion to keep https://jsfiddle.net/kmuq4g0w/5/ ... but really you will have a limit so short for that huge font text ?

Comment: now @mp3por if you really need that lower value on the first X container then use `word-break` that will solve the calculation https://jsfiddle.net/kmuq4g0w/6/

Answer (score 0):

Sooo...this is more complicated than you're thinking, due to word-breaks.  That is, if the midpoint of the text is in the middle of that word, that word will not break across both lines (that would be silly) so it wraps down to the next line:

```
somereallylongtextthatwillalwaysbetoolong somereallylongtextthatwillalwaysbetoolong dave
                                   midpoint ^
                                  max width v
somereallylongtextthatwillalwaysbetoolong   |
somereallylongtextthatwillalwaysbetoolong   |
dave
```

Which now makes *that* line too long, which causes the last word of to wrap down as well.  This could ultimately cascade quite a distance for more than 2 lines, but as more lines are added, the possibility for picking up the excess (due to wrapping a long word to a line that can then wrap a short word into available space) increases.

The solution I came to (in Unity) was to take an iterative approach: query how wide the text *wanted* to be if it was on one line.  Then just repeatedly subtract some width and checking the new *height* until it was at the desired ratio (I was interested in the width:height ratio in pixels, but the same applies to total lines: you can check for whether or not the needed height is the correct value).

So what I'd suggest doing is what you have now, but rather than "divide width by two, done" is to divide by two, check to see if the text's height is the expected value, and if not, add 50 pixels (arbitrary value) to the width and check again.  When the text's height drops down to the desired value, that's when the loop terminates.

Essentially, dividing by two will *always* be too short, unless it manages to catch right on a space, but that's also why it's a good starting point: we know we're *probably* close to the desired value.  Then all we have to do is keep adding a little more width (minimum the width of 1 character, because e.g. 1 pixel is unlikely to result in a change) until the size expands enough for that hanging word to pop back up a line.

```
                                  max width+2 v
somereallylongtextthatwillalwaysbetoolong     |
somereallylongtextthatwillalwaysbetoolong dave|
```

The same would occur regardless of where "dave" appears in this string. If it's first word, then it would be on its own line at the top.  Second, then its own line in the middle.  And in all three cases, just 2 more characters worth of width will always be enough for it to fit on the same line as one of the two "somereallylongtextthatwillalwaysbetoolong" portions.

Comment: I am currently implementing a very simple algorithm to do this. I will post it when I am done. I wanted to see how other people have done it. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Also in my case the first line can grow indefinitely ... this is a subsequence of the task

Comment: @mp3por a string of arbitrary length can still always fit on "at most two lines."  And "half its one line width" should still be a decent starting point in order to divide the string across two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout my answer which works : http://jsfiddle.net/mp3por/eq4e8dy7/10/

```
function getTextWidth(text, font) {
  var canvas = getTextWidth.canvas || (getTextWidth.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"));
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.font = font;

  var chunks = text.split(' ');
  var suggestedWidth = 130;
  var maxWidth = suggestedWidth;
  var chunkWidthMap = [];
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
    chunkWidthMap.push(context.measureText(chunks[i]).width);
  }
  // console.log(chunkWidthMap);

  var spaceWidth = context.measureText(' ').width;
  var line1Width = 0,
    line2Width = 0;
  var line1Chunks = [],
    line2Chunks = [];
  for (i = 0; i < chunkWidthMap.length; i++) {
    //console.log(`${i}: line1Width: ${line1Width}, line2Width: ${line2Width}, chunkWidth: ${chunkWidthMap[i]}`);
    //console.log(line1Chunks);
    //console.log(line2Chunks);
    if (line1Width + chunkWidthMap[i] < maxWidth && line2Width <= 0) {
      //console.log('Adding to 1st line');
      line1Width += chunkWidthMap[i] + spaceWidth;
      line1Chunks.push(i);
      continue;
    } else if (line2Width + chunkWidthMap[i] < maxWidth) {
      //console.log('Adding to 2nd line');
      line2Width += chunkWidthMap[i];
      line2Chunks.push(i);
      continue;
    } else {
      //console.log('not enough space in both => restructure');
      while (line2Width + chunkWidthMap[i] > maxWidth) {
        var line2FirstWordIndex = line2Chunks.shift();
        line2Width -= chunkWidthMap[line2FirstWordIndex] - spaceWidth;
        line1Width += chunkWidthMap[line2FirstWordIndex] + spaceWidth;
        line1Chunks.push(line2FirstWordIndex);
        maxWidth = line1Width;
      }
    }
  }

  console.log('maxWidth: ' + maxWidth);

  return maxWidth;
};

$('#sex').width(getTextWidth("total after-cashback revenue from rewarded users", "14px  'Roboto'"));
console.log(getTextWidth("total after-cashback revenue from rewarded users", "14px  'Roboto'"));
```

Comment: This is wrong. It calculates the linewidths wrong. I will fix it.